# Safari and CSS media queries

Tags: css, safari, media-queries

I have this CSS for desktop version:

```
div.bottomnav_table_left {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
}
div.bottomnav_table_spacer {
  width: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}
div.bottomnav_table_right {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

And this CSS for a small window version:

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  div.bottomnav_table_left {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
  }
  div.bottomnav_table_spacer {
    display: none;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
  }
  div.bottomnav_table_right {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
  }
  }
```

(I have tried limit the CSS code examples to the core. I hope that is okay.)

On IE, Opera, Chrome and FireFox I can resize window up and down and it works well. However, on Safari it will work on the initial size, but resizing the browser window will only work once.

If you resize Safari back (e.g. small to desktop to small) it no longer works. It does not place the DIVs on top of each other, instead they are placed next to each other horizontally.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and/or a live link to the problem?

Comment: There is likely to be problems trying to create a responsive layout using display:table-cell. If you want a div to act like a table cell, you shouldn't expect it to float or stack on top of each other.

Comment: Without a live example, it's hard to tell. To @Coop's second comment- I think they are on to something there. To the OP: have you tried setting `display:inline` on those elements within the media query?

Comment: @chipcullen I just tried **display:inline** but it does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: If I don't solve the problem soon, I will create a complete live example.